# Customize subentry indent and column width in index

Tags: indentation, indexing

I would like to change the indent space in index entries for subentries and page numbers.
I tried to use a customized  style file for makeindex, changed delim_x, changed parameters associated to lists, to no avail.
The enumitem package seems of no use here.
(I would like also to change column width.)
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the package idxlayout. The indentation is changed via e.g.:
\usepackage[hangindent=2em, subindent=0.8em]{idxlayout}
There is also a parameter columnsep to change the space between the columns.